# Triggering event after clicking on an link and loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

Below is a snippet of coffeescript:

```
$('a.view-more-link').on "click", ->
  newPageString = $(this).attr("href").replace(/page=(.*?)&/, (a,b) ->
    String("page=" + (Number(b) + 1) + "&")
  )
  $(this).attr "href", newPageString
```

I am using this method to increment the page number when I click the link. My expectations are that when I click the link, my content loads and appends to my diff and then the page number in the href increases:

`Started GET "/community?page=2&per=8" for 33.33.33.1` and then the href page increases from 2 to 3.

What is happening, however is that when I look at the request in rails console. I see that the newly incremented page number is being called instead:

`Started GET "/community?page=3&per=8" for 33.33.33.1`

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Ruling out other alternatives, how could I change just this script to fix my issue?

Thank you all for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

The default action for an `anchor` element is to navigate to the `href`, you will need to prevent this default action.

```
$('a.view-more-link').on 'click', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    ...
```